# SharePoint Office Web application failing to display document online Due to TLS1.0 Disablement

Tags: office-web-apps, tls

We have two load balancing server where SharePoint Farm is hosted and one Office web app server to view documents online. Since TLS1.0 is considered as weak protocol we have disabled TLS1.0 on SharePoint as well as OWA server. After disablement of TLS1.0 on SharePoint server, I am facing the above issue.

[image: Error while opening Document online]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look at the [Office Online Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/officeonlineserver/enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-support-in-office-online-server) guidance for enabling TLS 1.1 and 1.2 support; I do not know if Office Web Apps server was updated to support anything but TLS 1.0 and downlevel from there.